# Using UUID as id in ORMLite (Android)

Tags: android, ormlite

I have successfully created table with ORMLite, where it looks like it properly added uuid column as an primary key, index, etc.

```
public class Stat {
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    protected UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
...
```

Now, I'd like to be able to use full power of DAO provided and do (Stat is my class to be persisted, getUUID() returns UUID):

```
Stat statClassInstance = new Stat();
RuntimeExceptionDao<Stat, Integer> statDao = getHelper().getStatDataDao();

statDao.deleteById(statClassInstance.getUUID());
```

Compiler is giving me an error:

```
The method deleteById(Integer) in the type RuntimeExceptionDao<Stat,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (UUID)
```

What I'm missing is **how to use UUID ID's in methods such as deleteById**, which accept integer.
I've read that UUID as ID was incorporated into ORMLite, but no mention if it went only as far as enabling them to be primary keys, not supporting all those helper methods (queryForId, deleteIds) etc.

Comment: why dont you delete the record as statData.delete(statClassInstance). you usually override hashCode() equals() in the model class (your statClassInstance) and that should work fine as in example. you build a list of your records to delete then iterate and delete them.

Comment: More to  Fields With generatedId --- http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#SEC21

Comment: I frequently have situation where I have only UUID and not the object in question instantiated. Creating 'dummy' object only to delete it from DB doesn't look like efficient/clean way to do this.

Comment: yup, read the link. hope it will give you some insight.

Comment: UUID (DataType.UUID)
The java.util.UUID class persisted as a VARCHAR type. It saves it as the uuid.toString() and used the UUID.fromString(String) method to convert it back again. You can also mark a UUID field as being generated-id in which case whenever it is inserted, java.util.UUID.randomUUID() is called and set on the field.

Comment: I've read this documentation and it enabled me to put uuid as id's in Table. Now I'd like to be able use uuid's as id in all situations, like deleting record knowing only it's uuid (and not resorting to some complex use of queryForFieldValues methods).

Comment: OK do you have the exception which you get when you're trying to delete a record using your UUID field?

Comment: Compiler is not accepting UUID as an ID as deleteByID expects int, not UUID. "The method deleteById(Integer) in the type RuntimeExceptionDao<Stat,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (UUID)"

Comment: how did you create your Dao? Dao<Yourclass, Integer> mahDao =
    DaoManager.createDao(connSource, Yourclass.class); you should use the Dao<Yourclass,UUID>

Comment: Yes, thank you for that last piece of advice, it's been exactly the concept that was eluding me. As soon as I put those compiler error into message I started wondering if I could put UUID there, You confirmed my feelings. Please provide it as an answer so I can credit it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use the deleteById(ID) method the `Dao<T,ID>` should be created accordingly with corresponding parameters which have been identified in your T class. The ID will be interpreted as any type you define in your T class as a primary key. In this particular case it is UUID type and looking at the exception the DAO has been created using `Dao<Stat, Integer>` and should have been created as follows:

```
 Dao<Stat, UUID> statDao = DaoManager.createDao(connSource, Stat.class);
```

hope this helps

Comment: This is correct Sergey but it is better to provide some context here and not just the fix.

Comment: Sorry Sir, will do next time. The fix is provided for this particular case. I shall add more meat to it next time to describe it.

Comment: Np.  However, you should edit your answer to provide more context right now.  Remember that you are not only answering this question but also talking for posterity to the guy who pulls up this question a year from now.